# How to understand the very long confusing output of a command?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I have a complicated expression with many parameters

```
trE1 = βr - γ - γr - γs - 
  2 Λ - ν + 
  1/(2 (β - ν)) (-β βr + β γ - \
β γr - βr γs + β Λ - \
βr Λ + β ν + βr ν - γ \
ν + γr ν + γs ν - ν^2 + Sqrt[
     4 (β - βr) (γ γr + Λ (\
βr + γr - ν)) (β - ν) + (βr \
(γs + Λ) + β (βr - γ + \
γr - Λ - ν) - (βr - γ + \
γr + γs) ν + ν^2)^2]) - 
  1/(2 (β - ν) (βr - ν)) (β + 2 βr - 
     3 ν) (-((γ + γr + Λ) (β - \
ν)) - (βr - ν) (-β + γs + Λ \
+ ν) + Sqrt[
     4 (β - βr) (γ γr + Λ (\
βr + γr - ν)) (β - ν) + (βr \
(γs + Λ) + β (βr - γ + \
γr - Λ - ν) - (βr - γ + \
γr + γs) ν + ν^2)^2])
```

Mysteriously, Mathematica finds a unique root with respect to γ

```
Print["root=", 
 root = γ /. Solve[trE1 == 0, γ] // FullSimplify]
```

I wanted to check this. The following  commands took 4771 secs, so do not run them!

```
cp = {β > 0, βr > 0, Λ > 0, ν > 
    0, γ > 0, γr > 0, γs > 0};
Print["check sol?", 
 res = Timing[
   FullSimplify[trE1 //. γ -> root, Assumptions -> cp]]]
```

I could not understand what the very long output of Mathematica, appended below, meant. Incidentally, in numerical experiments, it turns out the computation is correct (trE1(root)=0). Any idea why the output is so confusing?

```
    {Piecewise[{{(4*\[Beta]*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) - 
            4*\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + (\[Gamma]r + \
    \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])^2)/(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \
    \[CapitalLambda]) + 
               ((\[Beta] - \[Beta]r)^2*(\[Beta]*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[CapitalLambda]) - \[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + \
    \[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])))/((\[Gamma]r + \
    \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*(\[Beta]r - \[Nu])^2) + 
               ((\[Beta] - \[Beta]r)*(4*\[Beta]*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[CapitalLambda]) - 4*\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + 
              3*\[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])))/((\
    \[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*(\[Beta]r - \[Nu])) + 
               ((\[Beta] - \[Beta]r)*(\[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]))/(-\
    \[Beta] + \[Nu]), (\[Beta] + \[Beta]r - 
            2*\[Nu])*(\[Beta]r - \[Nu])*(\[Beta]^4*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[CapitalLambda]) + 
                    \[Beta]r^3*(\[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*(\[Gamma]r \
    + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]) + \[Beta]r^2*(\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[CapitalLambda]) + (\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*(\
    \[Gamma]r - 3*(\[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])))*\[Nu] + 
                    \[Beta]r*(-4*\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) \
    - (\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*(\[Gamma]r - 
                  3*(\[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])))*\[Nu]^2 - 
                    (-4*\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + (\
    \[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])^2)*\[Nu]^3 + \[Beta]^3*(\
    \[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + \[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]) - 
                         
               5*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda])*\[Nu]) + \[Beta]^2*((-\
    \[Beta]r^2)*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + \[Beta]r*\[Gamma]r*(\
    \[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]) - \[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \
    \[CapitalLambda])*\[Nu] - 
  4*\[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])*\
    \[Nu] + 8*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda])*\[Nu]^2) + \
    \[Beta]*((-\[Beta]r^2)*(\[Beta]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + \
    \[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda])) +  5*\[Beta]r^2*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda])*\[Nu] + 
               4*((-\[Beta]r)*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda]) + \
    \[Gamma]r*(\[Gamma]r + \[Gamma]s + \[CapitalLambda]))*\[Nu]^2 - 
               4*(\[Gamma]r + \[CapitalLambda])*\[Nu]^3)) < 0}}, 0]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but you may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks. Just converting this in raw input form made the answer clearer. Assuming something very complicated is less than 0 (this part was not visible, at least on my screen), the answer is 0!  All's fine :)

Comment: This seems not to be a root for all possible values of the parameters. Evaluate several times the following. Sometimes you get zero (or near zero e.g. 10^-16). But sometimes you will get an answer of the order of magnitude of 1: trE1 /. \[Gamma] -> root[[1]] /. {\[Gamma]r -> 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}], \[Gamma]s -> 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}], \[CapitalLambda] -> 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}], \[Beta] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}], \[Beta]r -> 
   1, \[Nu] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}]}

Comment: Note the environment cuts off the backslash. You have to reinsert the backslash in front of every [...]